# Undefined Symbol Error

Tags: java, c++, c, gcc, arm

I am a java developer and compiling some C++ code to build a Shared Object to access it in Java. I can successfully build my 'so' file but when I load it using Java I get `undefined symbol: _ZTI18TransportFormatter` error. I did a grep for this symbol in my code and I found that the symbol is part of  `TcpFormatter.o and UdpFormatter.o`. Following is my make file. Please tell me if I am missing anything here.

P.S: I am building this on ARM processor. When I build this and run on a regular linux x86, I have no problems.

Thanks in Advance.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.3.3/
JDK_HOME=/home/skolli/native/java/include
CC=gcc
CCFLAGS=-c -O2
INCLUDE_DIRS=-I$(JDK_HOME) -I$(JDK_HOME)/linux
LIBS=/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
OBJ= Clock.o Constants.o IpFullAddress.o IcmpFormatter.o IpHeaderFormatter.o TcpFormatter.o UdpFormatter.o IcmpEchoFormatter.o IcmpErrorFormatter.o NetworkHandler.o IcmpTransfer.o jni_util.o JniConnector.o

icmpTransfer:   $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(LIBS) -shared -o libicmpTransfer.so $(OBJ)
Clock.o:        Clock.cpp Clock.h JniConnector.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(CCFLAGS) $*.cpp
Constants.o:        Constants.cpp Constants.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(CCFLAGS) $(FLAGS) $*.cpp
IcmpFormatter.o:        IcmpFormatter.cpp IcmpFormatter.h Constants.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(CCFLAGS) $*.cpp
IpHeaderFormatter.o:    IpHeaderFormatter.cpp IpHeaderFormatter.h Exception.h JniConnector.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(CCFLAGS) $*.cpp
TcpFormatter.o:         TcpFormatter.cpp TcpFormatter.h IpFullAddress.h IcmpFormatter.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(CCFLAGS) $*.cpp
UdpFormatter.o:     UdpFormatter.cpp UdpFormatter.h IpFullAddress.h TcpFormatter.h IcmpFormatter.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(CCFLAGS) $*.cpp
IcmpEchoFormatter.o:    IcmpEchoFormatter.cpp IpHeaderFormatter.h IcmpFormatter.h IpHeaderFormatter.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(CCFLAGS) $*.cpp
IcmpErrorFormatter.o:   IcmpErrorFormatter.cpp IcmpErrorFormatter.h IcmpEchoFormatter.h Exception.h IpHeaderFormatter.h IpFullAddress.h Exception.h JniConnector.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(CCFLAGS) $*.cpp
IpFullAddress.o:        IpFullAddress.cpp IpFullAddress.h Exception.h JniConnector.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(CCFLAGS) $*.cpp
NetworkHandler.o:       NetworkHandler.cpp NetworkHandler.h Clock.h IpFullAddress.h JniConnector.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(CCFLAGS) $*.cpp
IcmpTransfer.o:         IcmpTransfer.cpp IcmpTransfer.h IcmpFormatter.h IcmpEchoFormatter.h IcmpErrorFormatter.h IpHeaderFormatter.h NetworkHandler.h Clock.h TcpFormatter.h JniConnector.h UdpFormatter.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(CCFLAGS) $*.cpp
jni_util.o:         /home/skolli/native/share/TaCoreLib/jni_util.c /home/skolli/native/share/TaCoreLib/jni_util.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(CCFLAGS) $*.c
JniConnector.o:         JniConnector.cpp JniConnector.h ../TaCoreLib/jni_util.h com_attune_netally_ta_corelib_IcmpPacketTransfer.h Clock.h IcmpTransfer.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(CCFLAGS) $*.cpp


clean:
    -rm *.o
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an educated guess but it looks like your code uses RTTI (_ZTI18TransportFormatter = typeinfo for TransportFormatter), either directly by calling `dynamic_cast` or `typeid` or the compiler/linker will include it anyway if you don't explicitly disable it via the `-fno-rtti` option, but that's usually not available on embedded platforms.

Comment: When I did ldd -d I have the following. undefined symbol: _ZTV18TransportFormatter      (./libicmpTransfer.so)
undefined symbol: _ZTI18TransportFormatter      (./libicmpTransfer.so)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x4001e000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x400f6000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x4010c000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x4023b000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0x2a000000)

Comment: I got one of the undefined symbol erros resloved by using -fno-rtti. Now I only have undefined symbol:_ZTV18TransportFormatter error. Thanks.

Comment: @SatishK: without some actual code it's hard to figure stuff out. You may need to rewrite some of the stuff to not use virtual member functions.